# ImportError: No module named jinja2.filters - Python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, jinja2

In a work-production based Python program, I encountered a **Python import error** based issue.
I was able to replicate the issue using below lines of code:

**python-test.py**

```
from jinja2.filters import FILTERS, environmentfilter
from jinja2 import Template
import json, re, ast

print "test! There's actual code where the above modules are being used.."
```

I need to execute this code using Python 2.7.18
After I run: `python2 python-test.py` I'm getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "python-test.py", line 2, in 
> from jinja2.filters import FILTERS, environmentfilter
> ImportError: No module named jinja2.filters

I tried to install Jinja2 by running: `pip install Jinja2`. It got installed and yet still I'm getting this error.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you check: a) which version of jinja2 you have, b) where it is being imported from (write in your script `import jinja2; print(jinja2.__file__)` and execute it)

Comment: Possibly you have another python file that is shadowing jinja2

Comment: I did as you have suggested and created a file jinja.py and copied the contents that you have commented. When I ran `python2 jinja.py`, it threw an error stating that: **ImportError: No module named jinja2**. When I ran `python3 jinja.py`, it gave me: `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jinja2/__init__.py`

Comment: Think its okay with Python3, but I need to find a way to run using Python version 2.7.18.

Comment: This looks like you have not installed it for python2 yet. So You would need `python2 -m pip install "jinja2<3.0"`. Also, don't call your own py file `jinja`, that will possibly cause issues with the module

Comment: `pip install`, which you did before probably installed it for python3

Comment: When I ran `python2 -m pip install "jinja2<3.0"` it gave: **/usr/bin/python2: No module named pip**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243753/discussion-between-arjunbnair-and-flyingteller).